# Getting error while generating the unique id using Python

Tags: python, django

I am getting some error while generating the `unique id` using `uuid` in Python. I am explaining those error below.

> Error:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UUID found
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
import uuid
filename='+uuid.uuid4()+'.csv'
```

Here I need to put the file name as some unique id but getting the above error. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: That's not real code.

Comment: A UUID has multiple representations. Which one did you want?

Comment: Actually I need to keep one unique id as filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import uuid

filename = str(uuuid.uuid4()) + ".csv"
```

EDIT:

To avoid using string concatenation:

```
import uuid

filename = "%s.csv" % str(uuid.uuid4())
```

Comment: I would advocate for `"%s.csv" % uuid.uuid4()`, which is equivalent but avoids using the `+` operator on strings, which always is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import uuid
filename = '{}.csv'.format(uuid.uuid4().hex)
```

Comment: Look out! You dropped those `()` (after `uuid4`). Also: why using `hex`? I don't dislike it, but you should explain why --or provide both versions and say you like it more that way, if that's the case.

Comment: thanks. I used hex because i find the form more readable.... if that makes any sense